# how to debug jsp and javascript file in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

My project containing java files, applets, jsp and javascript file. I am able to debug applet and java files But not able to configure the debug setup for jsp and javascript files in eclipse.

I tried debug using F12 tools throw browser IE10 but those files are not coming under the project.

please mention the steps for configuring the debug setup

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Since the Javascript is executed on browser, Eclipse won't be able to debug it, unless it has some way to connect to the browser. You can try using [AJAX Toolkit Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/atf/), however, it's best to use internet browser's built-in debugger. You can also have a look at [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/).

If your javascript files are not appearing in the IE debugger:

- Check if the javascript files are included properly.
- Try debugger on Chrome or Firefox (or with Firebug extension on
  Firefox)

Also, you will not be able to place a debug pointer in JSP file unless it's placed in JAVA scriptlet part of JSP.